# Which beacon effect is the most useful for fending off raids?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a raid farm in my Minecraft bedrock, and I stopped doing raids to get a beacon. I watch LTN on YouTube, and he uses beacons to make the raids easy. Which effect (speed, haste, strength, regeneration, jump boost, resistance) would help the most in this situation to constantly fend off raids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your options:

- Speed: You can easily outrun a ravager chasing after you, and also use strength to kill it with a bow.
- Haste: It is used to mine blocks faster, not for attacking mobs. This option is not really for raids.
- Strength: By far the most necessary. It helps destroy all mobs, either melee or projectile damage being used.
- Regeneration: It could be used to help get your health back whilst backing off, unless you have a sufficient amount of food to keep you alive (suggesting cooked porkchop or beef), this option can be used.
- Jump Boost: Not really an option, but if you were to get rid of ravagers, use a subtle amount of jump boost, get on a roof and snipe them.
- Resistance: Similar to regeneration, but more effective. If you are too weak (even with strength), you can use this effect to fight a bit more longer.

If you don't have a beacon though and still can't make potions, stack up on cooked food and wear armor (either diamond or netherite) to win the raid faster, even without effects (unless a witch comes and hits you with poison).

Answer (score -1):

Most of these effects would be helpful for raids except for haste... It just depends on your taste. Personally, I might choose resistance, regen or speed as they are more helpful in player vs mob combat. Hope this helps!